# How to display details to Flask-Python

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a python file **(plant.py)** which gives me information about specific plants from an **API**.

```
import requests
import pprint

printer = pprint.PrettyPrinter()


plant_name = "peace lily".strip().lower()

url = f"https://house-plants.p.rapidapi.com/common/{plant_name}"

headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "API-KEY",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "house-plants.p.rapidapi.com"
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

# print(printer.pprint(response))

latin_name = response[0]["latin"]
climate = response[0]["climate"]
tempmax = response[0]["tempmax"]
watering = response[0]["watering"]
diseases = response[0]["diseases"]
use = response[0]["use"][0]
```

Now given below is my main flask file called **app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/result")
def result():
    return render_template("result.html", Plant_name=request.args.get("Plant_name", "World"))
```

To give the purpose of this file, I have made the **index.html** which prompts the user to enter a plant's name, and the **app.py** changes the route to **result.html** and will display the **info about that plant(from the API)** in that page.

Given below is the code of **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Taviraj&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Gist of it</title>

    <style>
      .form-block {
        margin: auto;
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 18px;
        width: 250px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border-color: #00203f;
        border: none;
        text-align: center;
      }
      input::placeholder {
        color: #00203f;
        font-family: "Taviraj", serif;
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 0.7;
      }

      .btn {
        display: block;
        margin: auto;
        border: none;
        padding: 12px;
        width: 100px;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: "Rubik", sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: #33b249;
        border-radius: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease;
      }

      .btn:hover {
        transform: translate(0px, -6px);
      }
      #TitleWords {
        font-family: "Taviraj", serif;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 55px;
        color: #00203f;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#ADEFD1">
    <div id="TitleWords">
      <p>Plantast</p>
    </div>

    <!-- Form -->
    <form action="/result" method="get">
      <input
        class="form-block"
        type="text"
        autocomplete="off"
        placeholder="Plant Name"
        name="Plant_name"
      />
      &nbsp;
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

[web view of **index.html**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5QIr.png)

Code of **result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Taviraj&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Plant result</title>

    <style>
      #TitleWords {
        font-family: "Taviraj", serif;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 55px;
        color: #00203f;
      }

      #Plant_name {
        font-family: "Taviraj", serif;
        text-align: left;
        position: relative;
        left: 30px;
        color: #f8c301;
        font-size: 22px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#ADEFD1">
    <div id="TitleWords">
      <p>Plantast</p>
    </div>

    <h2 id="Plant_name">{{Plant_name}}</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

[web view of **result.html**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il4PY.png)

I aim to display the details of the **plant from the API** in the **result.html** and am stuck in this.

If you have any ideas on how to get this done I have no idea and broke my head on this.

Comment: Please put code as code blocks in the question, rather than as screen captures.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have done the required modifications to ease the process of solving the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to simply import the *plant.py* to the python flask app then, pass the results to the html.

One way is to create a function in the *plant.py* that returns the result of the search:

```
def result():
dict = {
    latin_name: response[0]["latin"]
    climate: response[0]["climate"]
    tempmax: response[0]["tempmax"]
    watering: response[0]["watering"]
    diseases: response[0]["diseases"]
    use: response[0]["use"][0] 
}
return dict
```

Then import the *plant.py* to the flask app, and add the returned value as a variable in the render template

```
@app.route("/result")
def result():

    plant_dict = plant.result()

    return render_template("result.html", result=plant_dict Plant_name=request.args.get("Plant_name", "World"))
```

You can then use the dict in the *result.html* to display the information.